# Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Hello I'm trying to use redux in a react-native app and I get the error mentioned in the title, specifically `Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)"`. I'm not sure what is the problem and although I followed similar threads nothing worked so far.

Bellow is my App.js source

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as utils from './src/utils';
import store from './src/store';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }

    login({ username, password }) {

        let requestData = new FormData();

        requestData.append('username', username);
        requestData.append('password', password);

        console.log('[Login]: Attempt');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(requestData, null, 4));

        fetch('https://my-api.lab/user/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: requestData
        }).then(res => res.json()).then((json) => {

            console.log('[Login]: Response');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));

            if (json.authenticated) {

                console.log('[Login]: Success');

                this.props.userLoginSuccess(json);

            } else {
                console.log('[Login]: Failure');
            }

        }).catch((err) => {

            console.log('[Login]: error');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));

        });

    }

    componentDidMount() {

        console.log('App mounted!');

        this.login({
            username: 'asdf',
            password: 'asdf'
        });

    }

    render() {

        let username = Object.keys(this.props.user).length ? this.props.user.data.post.username : '';

        return (

            <Provider store={store}>

                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                        Welcome {username} to React Native!
                    </Text>
                </View>

            </Provider>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.userReducer
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

    return {

        userLoginSuccess: (user) => {

            dispatch({
                type: 'USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS',
                payload: user
            })

        },

        userLoginFailure: (user) => {

        }

    }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Also here is my index.js file

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('pushNotificationsNative', () => App);
```

The store

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index.js';

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer
);

export default store;
```

and finally a simple reducer

```
import deepExtend from 'deep-extend';

const initialState = {};

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case 'USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS': {
            return deepExtend({}, state, action.payload);
        }

        default: {
            return deepExtend({}, state);
        }

    }

}

export default userReducer;
```

Comment: I'm still looking at the rest of the code, but why are you using a spread in the constructor? You actually don't even need the constructor here as you aren't doing anything in it. You only do this if you actually need to do something when the class is constructed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access the store in the App component whereas, your Provider resides inside it. So, App doesn't really get store from the context. You need to wrap App with Provider like

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }

    login({ username, password }) {

        let requestData = new FormData();

        requestData.append('username', username);
        requestData.append('password', password);

        console.log('[Login]: Attempt');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(requestData, null, 4));

        fetch('https://my-api.lab/user/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: requestData
        }).then(res => res.json()).then((json) => {

            console.log('[Login]: Response');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));

            if (json.authenticated) {

                console.log('[Login]: Success');

                this.props.userLoginSuccess(json);

            } else {
                console.log('[Login]: Failure');
            }

        }).catch((err) => {

            console.log('[Login]: error');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));

        });

    }

    componentDidMount() {

        console.log('App mounted!');

        this.login({
            username: 'asdf',
            password: 'asdf'
        });

    }

    render() {

        let username = Object.keys(this.props.user).length ? this.props.user.data.post.username : '';

        return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                        Welcome {username} to React Native!
                    </Text>
                </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.userReducer
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

    return {

        userLoginSuccess: (user) => {

            dispatch({
                type: 'USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS',
                payload: user
            })

        },

        userLoginFailure: (user) => {

        }

    }

}

const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

export default const Root = () => {
    <Provider store={store}><ConnectedApp/></Provider>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `App` wrapped in a connect() method but are instantiating the `<Provider>` component in `App`. My hunch is that at this point there is no `store` for connect to access and give to `App`. Try removing the connect statement and see if that resolves your issue.

You have code that depends on data from store, I would comment that out for the time being to see if the above solution works. If it does, make app just a simple component that stands up the store and move the code for doing login and checking user to a new component.

Answer (score 1):

Provider must wrap a higher-level component. 
Lower-level component, or nested component imported to the one with provider, should have the connect function.

Top-level(index.js):

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Higher-level component(app.js):

```
const store = createStore(reducers);
const App = () => {
    return <Provider store={store}>
        <UI/>
    </Provider>;
};
export default App;
```

Lower-level/nested(ui.js)

```
const UI = () => {
return <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>;
};
export default connect()(UI);
```

This issue is specific to react-native, because in react, we typically wrap App within index.js, which is not the case for RN.